# Macports mysql5 setup under Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I've managed to get my install all screwed up as I'm a newbie and messing up is what I'm good at.

1) Can anyone reference a credible set of setup instructions for this stuff?

2) Can I just uninstall and start from scratch (passwords and all) through macports? I tried and a bunch of mysql directories stuck around after the unistall, WTF!?

3) Where does mysqld.sock need to reside and what file settings do I need to apply to get it playing nice with php5 and apache2 ? 
Does it live in /tmp or in /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/ ? 
Do I need to configure /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini? opt/local/var/db/php5/mysql.ini? /opt/local/etc/mysql5/my.cnf?

4) I've run > sudo -u mysql mysql_install_db5. If I run it again will it mess me up?
I ran mysqladmin -u root password 'mypw' and got an error saying the mysql could not connect through the socket. So does this mean my password is now set? Is there a way I can tell?

5) The syntax of the password statement changes from blog to blog. Is my password 'mypw' or mypw (without the quotes)? (My password is not actually mypw)

6) What are the appropriate commands to start and stop mysql? I DO NOT want it to start when my machine starts.

---

Thanks Jergason, that's tremendously helpful.

I'd really like to stay consistent with the macports installation of mysql since it limits the damage I can do to my machine.

So the outstanding questions now are...

1) What is the default socket location for the macports mysql install?

2) What are the appropriate commands to start and stop mysql? I DO NOT want it to start when my machine starts. Some blogs say to use launchctl -load others say sudo /path/mysql_safe5. If you havn't set the password (as I don't intend to) do you need to use the -user -p parameters?

3) What are the necessary directory ownerships and permissions to get macports mysql working. It doesn't seem that macports sets any of that.

---

Nerdling

> Check /tmp for the MacPorts mysql socket

Not helpful. As previously stated, I understand that /tmp is the default location for the socket. My problem is that when I attempt to start mysql the socket does not materialize there, nor does it appear in /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/. This tells me I have a problem starting mysql, which means there is something wrong with the setup. What it could be, I don't know. I'm afraid I wasn't born with an a priori knowledge of such things.

-What SPECIFIC directory SHOULD the socket be in for the mysql5 install using macports under Snow Leopard?

> If you're using 5 different sites' tips on how to run mysql and you're surprised you've gotten lost … well, I'll just leave it at try to follow just one site at a time and back out all changes before going to the next.

Not helpful. I did exactly what you're suggesting to begin with. What do you think I did, mix and match instructions from 5 blogs? This is why I asked about clean uninstalls. I wanted to know if a state change from a previous install could effect future "clean" installs.

-What SPECIFIC blog describes the confirmed-to-be-correct install procedure of mysql5 using macports under Snow Leopard.

> I think the only problem you're having with MacPorts mysql (what problem are you having??) is that it's got a socket where you don't expect it and it's using a default configuration.

Not helpful. Me too, see my original post. I think the problem lies with how mysql is started (or isn't starting).

-Do you have any SPECIFIC suggestions on how to correct the problem?

> This should have been explained after the install was completed by MacPorts.

Not helpful. It wasn't, or I didn't see it if it was. Maybe because I was using Porticus.

-Could you be more SPECIFIC? At WHAT point should I have seen WHAT message?

> Please see ${prefix}/share/doc/mysql5/ for ideas and/or contact the developer list. Also consider contacting the maintainer of the port; they likely know the most about it since they manage it.

Not helpful. RTM, Google is your friend, and all that. Yep, went there first. Although I will admit I may have overlooked something as I'm not inclined to spend days reading some poorly written docs when I have other work to do to when I'm sure my problem is a simple one.

- If you want to give me a SPECIFIC document that I may have overlooked, THAT would be helpful.

I was hoping for some simple, focused help like what Jergason provided. I (and others reading this) appreciate Jergason's willingness to convey his knowledge in order to accelerate the learning process of people new to various technologies. To him, the knowledge is basic, but to new-comers it's a massive time-saver. The true mark of intelligence is the understanding that technology knowledge is not a priori and that even basic help is of great help. Thanks again J-man.

Comment: Have you looked at MAMP? I had a bit of a hard time getting mysql up and running on snow leopard on a short timeframe, and MAMP worked fine.

Answer (score 13):

I've just installed mysql5 myself, and since this is always a pain I've noted the process that I followed. This was done on Leopard, but I imagine the process is the same on Snow Leopard and Lion. It doesn't answer all the original questions, but at least it's something of a guide.

### Installing Mysql

First, install mysql5 server with:

```
sudo port install mysql5-server
```

Just installing `mysql5` doesn't install the server.

Pay attention to the console output, it includes instructions for setting up macports. You might want to copy and paste it to a text file. The following is based on it.

Instead of `mysql5-server`, you could use a port such as `mysql55-server`, `mysql56-server`, `mariadb-server` or `percona-server` to get a more recent version of mysql, or a fork. If you do, pay attention to the console output, as the following instructions are based on `mysql5-server` and will need to be adjusted to use the correct executables and paths.

If this is a new install, set up the database:

```
sudo -u _mysql mysql_install_db5
```

That outputs some generic instructions, which I don't think are entirely appropriate for macports. In my opinion the best way to load mysql5 as a daemon is to use macport's method:

```
sudo port load mysql5-server
```

As well as starting mysql5, this permanently loads it - it will run on boot up. To stop this later:

```
sudo port unload mysql5-server
```

If you don't want to run it as a daemon, you can run it at the command line:

```
sudo /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqld_safe
```

Check that it's running by logging in at the command line:

```
mysql5 -u root -p
```

By default, the password is empty, so just press enter when prompted. To set a root password:

```
/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'correct horse battery staple'
```

Instructions for setting up both macports php and the native php installation follow.

### Setup Macports PHP

Assuming you've already got macports php installed and running. You need to install `php5-mysql` (or something like `php54-mysql` depending on which version of php you're using):

```
sudo port install php5-mysql
```

This installs the mysql, mysqli and pdo drivers.

Now look in your `/opt/local/etc/php5` directory, if you don't already have a `php.ini` configuration file copy either `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` to `php.ini`. Now edit `php.ini` and search for the appropriate lines to add:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

and:

```
mysql.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

and:

```
mysqli.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

If you don't want to configure these, you can set them explicitly in your php script when you connect.

If you're having trouble connecting you might want to look at the other nearby settings, and compare with `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` to see what's been changed.

Then use the script below, or something similar to test that you can connect with php.

### Setup System PHP

OS X's php comes with mysql and mysqli support built in (but not pdo), so all you need to do is set the macport unix socket. The default location is `/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock`. Find the correct place in `/etc/php.ini` (if you don't have it already, copy it from `/etc/php.ini.default`) to add:

```
mysql.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

and:

```
mysqli.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

If you don't want to configure these, you can set them explicitly in your php script when you connect.

### Test Script

Here's a php script to check that it can connect. Obviously, you won't normally use the root account in your php scripts so you might want to first create another mysql account for testing the connection. The PDO connection won't work for native php since that doesn't have PDO drivers.

```
<?php

$username = 'root';
$password = 'correct horse battery staple';

/* Try mysql: */

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
if ($connection === FALSE) {
    echo "Error connecting using mysql.\n\n";
    echo "Error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n\n";

}
else {
    echo "Connected using mysql.\n\n";
    mysql_close($connection);
}

/* Try mysqli: */

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    echo "Error connecting using mysqli:\n\n";
    echo "Error ".$connection->connect_errno.": ".$connection->connect_error."\n\n";
}
else {
    echo "Connected using mysqli.\n\n";
    $connection->close();
}

/* Try pdo:
 * Won't work for the version of php supplied with OS X. */

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', $username, $password);
    echo "Connected using PDO.\n\n";
    $pdo = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error connecting using PDO:\n\n";
    echo "Error ".$e->getCode().": ".$e->getMessage()."\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Well done, sir. Also keep in mind that you need not use the local socket for MySQL but identifying your connection as `localhost` will always try to. Use `127.0.0.1` (yes, technically the same but not to good ole PHP) to force a TCP connection and bypass the misconfigured socket.

Answer (score 4):

I've just run into the same issue myself. To get my MySQL working, I simply had to do

```
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
```

The attempt to do sudo -u _mysql mysql_db5 failed, but I could then do

```
mysqladmin -u root  password the_new_password
```

without any problem.

If you don't want MySQL to start automatically when you turn the machine on, simply do this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
```

Then to start/stop MySQL:

start:

```
sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper start
```

stop:

```
sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper stop
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also had a problem where sudo -u _mysql mysql_db5 failed.  I followed Matt's directions and the db started.  (OSX 10.6.8)

Comment: Also, I added this path to my .bash_login so I wouldn't have to type the full path every time.  'export PATH=/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin:$PATH'
.  Then did a source .bash_login to reload the path.

Comment: MacPorts also includes a handy command for loading and unloading the launchctl plists, try: `sudo port load mysql5-server` (also works for `apache2`, btw)

Answer (score 2):

1)[Hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/u/696) has a great walkthrough on compiling mysql for Snow Leopard from the source. It is not actually that difficult, and if you do it yourself you will know where it is.

2) You should be able to just run `sudo port uninstall mysql5`. It may yell at you about dependencies. If so you will have to uninstall those first. Uninstalling MySQL should remove all config settings including passwords.

*3) Where does mysqld.sock need to reside and what file settings do I need to apply to get it playing nice with php5 and apache2 ?* The location of mysqld.sock is less important than the path to it. You set the path to mysqld.sock in your php.ini file. If you have a php.ini file in /opt/local/bin, then you installed the macports version of php. You can use that one, or you can use the default Apple version. Either way, you need to configure the php.ini file in order to tell your php installation where to go to use it. There should be a line in your php.ini file that says

```
mysql.default_socket = <whatever>
```

If it is not there, you can add it. You should set this line equal to the location of your mysqld.sock. Mine looks like this:

```
mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Your Apache configuration

*4) I've run > sudo -u mysql mysql_install_db5. If I run it again will it mess me up? I ran mysqladmin -u root password 'mypw' and got an error saying the mysql could not connect through the socket. So does this mean my password is now set? Is there a way I can tell?* If you could not connect to the socket, then your password was not set.

*5) The syntax of the password statement changes from blog to blog. Is my password 'mypw' or mypw (without the quotes)? (My password is not actually mypw)* You don't need the quotes around the password in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Check /tmp for the MacPorts mysql socket.

If you're using 5 different sites' tips on how to run mysql and you're surprised you've gotten lost … well, I'll just leave it at try to follow just one site at a time and back out all changes before going to the next.

I think the only problem you're having with MacPorts mysql (what problem are you having??) is that it's got a socket where you don't expect it and it's using a default configuration.  This should have been explained after the install was completed by MacPorts.  Please see `${prefix}/share/doc/mysql5/` for ideas and/or contact the [developer list](http://macports.org/).

Also consider contacting the maintainer of the port; they likely know the most about it since they manage it.

Answer (score 1):

the php.ini being used on the command line may be different than the one being used by apache
You can check this with 
phpinfo.php

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?
```

by doing a

```
php phpinfo.php | grep php.ini
```

if it shows

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/local/etc/php5
```

and the test script of Daniel James answer (saved as testconnect.php) also fails

then you might want to fix by creating a symbolic link:

```
/opt/local/etc/php5>sudo ln -s /etc/php.ini php.ini
```

after that the testconnect should work

```
php testconnect.php 
Connected using mysql.
Connected using mysqli.
Connected using PDO.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  Despite the fact that Apache was not running, for some reason Apache was blocking MySQL from running (and thus from creating the socket). (Yea, weird right?) Before I ran the install, I issued the command to stop apache, then the install went swimmingly. Even now, before I start MySQL, I first have to tell Apache (which is not running) to stop.

And just for the record, I know it's not running because I get 
"httpd (no pid file) not running"
I'm not having it run automatically on start up or any bone-head crap like that.

I'll try to write up a walk-through so that no one else has to go through this BS.

Answer (score 0):

When installing php5 via macports the package doesn't come automatically with mysql extension, so it cannot connect to mysql via php (but you probably can through command line).

Let's check first if your mysql is running properly:

```
mysqladmin5 -uroot -pYOURROOTPASSWORD ping
```

If it's alive, you can verify all the variables by:

```
mysqladmin5 -uroot -pYOURROOTPASSWORD variables
```

You should see your "socket" location is defined as

```
/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

Using macports install missing components in 2 minutes... here's how:

```
sudo port install php5-mysql
```

To use mysqlnd with a local MySQL server, edit **/opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini** and set
mysql.default_socket, mysqli.default_socket and pdo_mysql.default_socket
to **/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock**

Then to restart your Apache type:

```
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart
```

Now everything should be up and running properly. Hope that helps.